# How to correctly implement a parallax effect based on the scrolling of the user?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been following [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wfeqDyMUx4&t=811s) on how to make a parallax website. Everything was going well until I got to line 44 of my index.html file: `moon.style.left = value * 1.05 + 'px';` There was no error code, it just didn't do what it did in the video at [15:52](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wfeqDyMUx4&t=949s), where it slides depending on your scrolling.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parallax Scrolling Website | Vanilla Javascript</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
        <section class="parallax-section">
            <img src="Background (1).png" id="background">
            <img src="Back Mountains.png" id="back_mountains">
            <img src="Front Mountains.png" id="front_mountains">
            <img src="Moon.png" id="moon">
            <img src="Ocean.png" id="ocean">
            <h2 id="text">Moon Light</h2>
            <a href="#sec" id="btn">Explore</a>
            <img src="Weird land_.png" id="weird_land">
        </section>
        <div class="sec" id="sec">
            <h2>Parallax Scrolling Effects</h2>
            <p>Something Something Something <br><br> Something Something Something</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            let Background = document.getElementById('background');
            let Back_mountains = document.getElementById('back_mountains');
            let Front_mountains = document.getElementId('front_mountains');
            let Moon = document.getElementById('moon');
            let Ocean = document.getElementById('ocean');
            let Text = document.getElementById('text');
            let Btn = document.getElementById('btn');
            let Weird_land = document.getElementById('weird_land');

            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
                let value = window.scrollY;
                moon.style.left = value * 1.05 + 'px';
                back_mountains.style.top = value * -1.25 + 'px';
                front_mountains.style.top = value * .5 + 'px';
                text.style.marginTop = value * 2 + 'px';
            })
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body
{
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(#01789c, #1c0130);
}

header
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10000;
}

header .logo
{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header ul
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

header ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px
}

header ul li a:hover, header ul li a.active
{
    background: #fff;
    color: #2b1055;
}

section
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #1c0522, transparent);
    z-index: 1000;
}

section img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    pointer-events: none;
}

section img#moon
{
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

section img#mountains_front
{
    z-index: 10;
}

#text
{
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 7.5vw;
    z-index: 9;
}

#btn
{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #2b1055;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    z-index: 9;
    transform: translateY(100px);
}

.sec
{
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px;
    background: #1c0522;
}

.sec h2
{
    font-size: 3.5em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.sec p
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I tried to change the `.left` to `.top` to see if it would do anything but it's still static. I also tried changing the values to see if maybe that would have an effect, still nothing. I expected it to slide according to the scrolling like in the video, but nothing happened and it remained static.

Comment: so the `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementId is not a function` isn't an error?

Comment: This is so much work for a parallax effect, you could probably get away with a css only solution using `view`. Check out [kevin powell's demo](https://youtu.be/UmzFk68Bwdk). Though it doesnt have a ton of support for old browsers.

Comment: @asyncawait or safari, or firefox ... without the polyfill 100 times the size of this code - though, firefox does have a config flag to enable the CSS used by Mr Powell, but then the polyfill completely breaks firefox if you use it and enable the flag ... so, not a good cross browser solution yet

Comment: Consider using a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make your code runnable within your question. It just makes it a bit easier for answerers helping you :)